# Removing a word from a previously created file using shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Suppose we do have a previously created file  **ABC**

```
cat ABC      //Checking contents of **ABC**

hello
hi 
how
what
where
```

> Now with the help of shell script i do want to remove the word 'how' from **ABC**

**I am trying this**

```
echo Enter file name 
read a
if[ $a -f ]
then
_____ |grep how ABC
fi
```

Is there any command which can be used at _____?

All other solution are also welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `sed`:

```
read -p "Enter file name: " file
[[ -f "$file" ]] && sed -i.bak '/how/d' ABC
```

`/how/d` will delete line with the pattern `how` in file `ABC` if found and save the changes back into `ABC`. It also creates a backup of original file with the name `ABC.bak` in case something goes wrong.

In case you want to replace only a single word (without deleting whole line containing that word) then use:

```
sed -i.bak 's/how//' ABC
```

Comment: You are deleting the whole line containing word `how`, you should use substitute instead, such as `sed 's/how//g' ABC`

Comment: Thanks anubhava ,
But is it possible to delete the word 'how' using grep and other command as i mentioned above.

Comment: Why do you want to use a command (`grep`, which just does search text) to delete some text, instead of another (`sed`), which is able to both search text and delete it from a file?

Comment: @MarcoS just curious if it is possible

Comment: ... So you should change your question deleting the sentence "All other solution(s) are also welcome." and adding "the command should use a `grep`". But I suppose it should have a very diminished interest... :-)

Comment: @Gulshan: `grep` is not the tool for substitution. If words are on separate lines then you can use: `grep -v 'how' file` to get all the lines except matching pattern.

Comment: @MarcoS I have already accepted the answer by anubhava.It's just i am curious if using **pipe** and other command with **grep** is it possible to delete the word.
Hopefully i am clear about it now.

Comment: It is not. Grep is not a tool for substitution. You were very clear.

Comment: I never have asked for substituting the word, i have asked for removing/deleting the word.It's just substituting here doing the task and that's the reason i have accepted the answer.But still i am curious if this can be done  '____ |grep word filename'

Comment: @anubhava really appreciate your answer,but as far as i know **grep -v** will only display the desired result but will not make changes to the original file ABC.
I mean we can also perform above task like this
**grep -v how ABC > ABCD** and then deleting file ABC and then moving contents of ABCD to newly created ABC.
But i do want to keep it simple like '___|grep how ABC'
If it is possible.

Comment: Now you see why sed is better :) Anyway you could do: `grep -v 'how' ABC > _tmp && mv _tmp ABC`